# Chrome Frame working on other sites in IE7 but not mine

Tags: google-chrome-frame

In the head I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=IE7">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.attachEvent("onload", function(){ CFInstall.check({ mode: "overlay", destination: "http://www.websitename.com" }); });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

When the site loads, if you don't have Chrome Frame installed it does prompt you to install it. You can then install Chrome Frame but when it is done installing, the site still does not display. I can see the difference in other sites that use Chrome Frame before and after I have installed it so I know that Chrome Frame is actually installing and working. I do get a message saying

> An error has occurred in this dialog
>
> Error:153
>
> Unspecified error

Any thoughts would be very helpful and appreciated

Comment: I'm running into a similar error. I wish I knew what it meant!